# Can I use the zero article?

Tags: articles

In the following sentence, can I use the zero article before 'important means' instead of 'an'?

> Newspapers are still (an) important means of communication.

Comment: What do you mean by zero article?

Comment: @BellaSwan He means omitting the article. `zero article == no article`.

Comment: You mean use the plural to make a general statement?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can omit 'an' in the sentence 'Newspapers are still (an) important means of communication.' When the 'an' is omitted, the word 'means' becomes plural. It happens that the singular and plural forms of 'means' are identical.

Comment: You could substitute *method* and *methods* for with and without the *an* to demonstrate the plurality?

Comment: For "method" you would need to say "an important method". It only works for means because it can be both singular or plural. [This ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10343/is-means-plural-or-singular) post asks a similar question. @Simon, (Welcome to ELL) in future, please try and reference a source :)